# Parsing problem in android

Tags: android, saxparser

I have create an android  application where parse data using saxparser .But Problem is that it does not parse the whole string inside the tag. The first 4 or 5 word is shown. Why i do not able to parse the whole string inside the tag. I follow the site....

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Please help me . Thank in advance.

Comment: show your code over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the character method of your xml handler

```
public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if (buf!=null) {
        for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++) {
            buf.append(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Where buf is a string builder.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed has a bug in their characters method. The characters method may be called multiple times per tag, so you need to append the characters to your current value rather than starting a new String.